# Xamarin Forms Unhandled exception on a ListView in a TableView

Tags: xamarin.forms, tableview, xamarin.forms.listview

I'm trying to dabble a bit by moving from WPF to Xamarin using MVVM, and as the title says, I'm having a problem.

I first tried this code in a ContentPage XAML with a ListView, like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EmailList}">
    <TextCell Text="{Binding .}" />
</ListView>
```

and the EmailList is just a simple `List<string>`. I've tested it, and it works. I get a list of strings ("abc@test.com", "john@doe.com", etc)

I then try my luck doing a TableView, with the Intent set at Form in XAML. I did a few TableSelections, like Name, Address, etc, and they seem to work fine. However, when I put this in:

```
<TableSection Title="Emails">
   <ViewCell>
     <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EmailList}">
        <TextCell Text="{Binding .}"/>
    <ListView>
  <ViewCell>
</TableSection>
```

This is when I get an unhandled exception error and the app drops out.

I then tried this:

```
  <TableSection Title="Emails">
 <ViewCell>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EmailList}">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <ViewCell>
                  <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
               <ViewCell>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
 </ViewCell>
```

And I still get the same unhandled exception error.

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't think putting a ListView inside of a Table is a good idea.  Both are implemented (I believe) as UITableViews, and nesting tables is generally a bad idea.

Comment: I was hoping that it wouldn't be the case. I'm wondering... can I use a ContentView within the ViewCell?

Comment: I think a ViewCell is already the Cell equivalent of a ContentView - both have a single Content property, which could be any control or layout

Comment: Like @Jason says; you should not want this. So maybe take a step back; what is it that you are trying to achieve? Maybe we can provide you with an alternative, instead of making this bad practice trying to work.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that I cannot find the reason for it, and what other guys are saying in the comments, I think I have to take another approach. I'll have to go old school here and use a StackLayout and/or Grids to achieve on what I need the app to do.

Thanks for your input guys!